# Development server & production server

Tags: django, apache, vps

What is the right way to handle a production and development website on the same server? the development code shouldn't be available until it's used for production.
I'm using Apache and Django and VPS hosting. 
What should I configure? Apache- so it will have a special prefix for development stuff, Django- and have some URL mangling in the urlconf, or just get another VPS for development?

Comment: Production and development on the same server is ALWAYS wrong. The more you can separate them the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find an old computer and stick it in your basement.  you really don't need tons of horsepower for a dev machine & should be able to do it for a couple hundred bucks. 
The problem with developing on a production machine is that you could crash processes [apache?] with some 'not quite debugged yet' code and affect live services, even if you have configured separate subdomains or virtual hosts.

never never never develop live.

-sean

PS> another VPS is a workable solution if 'spare hardware' is not available. However you could have availability issues.

Comment: in a shared hosting enviroment where there are hundreds of users how come no one crashes the apache server?

Comment: generally speaking an experienced shared host will be on top of that sort of thing but yes it does happen - I have seen it. most recently with a c compiled cgi for a shopping cart - through testing we found tht if some one tries to checkout with a basket over $1,000,000.00 the cgi would hog 100% cpu and hang, subsequent requests would do the same resulting in dozens of CGIs trying to hog 100% cpu, forcing the whole server to a crawl, [all services! DB/mail/DNS etc] the processes had to be killed manually. Java is good for that sort of thing too...

Comment: thank you very much for the insightful example. To mitigate this sort of problem would you use many little VPS-es with a load balancer? if one crashes and burnes, the other can continue working. You would lose only the processes on that instance, not every process. Although I think it's really complicated to implement

Comment: well, no you would use load balancing if you expect heavy loads, the issue will turn up on all servers in the cluster eventually. the correct solution is to fix the problem [in my case at least]